# Python: Importing a text file to make sublist separated by '#'

Tags: python, python-3.x, readfile, sublist

I am trying to read a text file and have a it as a sublist. Each sublist is separated by a line that contain only '#'. Example of text file:

```
#
1  2
3  4
#
5  6
7  8
```

This image would be a better representation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVc0q.jpg)

The result should be: `[[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]]`

This is what I have come up with:

```
file=open(file_name)
contents=[]
for row in file:
    stripped_row=row.strip()
    row_list=stripped_row.split()
    contents.append(row_list)
file.close()
```

The result I get is `[['#'], ['2.1,-3.1'], ['-0.7,4.1'], ['#'], ['3.8,1.5'], ['-1.2,1.1']]`

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a nested list comprehension.

```
with open(file_name) as file_handle:
    contents = [
        [
            [
                float(item)
                for item in line.split()
            ]
            for line in block.strip().splitlines()
        ]
        for block in file_handle.read().strip('#\r\n').split('#')
    ]
print (content)
```

Comment: @Proofnothing10x: Yes, you can do it without list comprehensions, but then the code becomes more cumbersome, because you’ll have to initialize the various sub-lists (`… = []`) and use `.append` every time.

Comment: By the way, I edited the code to return floats instead of strings, as you seem to want floats as the items of the sub-lists. Note that you want three levels of lists (in my code they’re called block, line, item), so you need three nested loops or list comprehensions. I’ve tried to format the code in a way that the structure becomes clear.

Answer (score 0):

File:

```
#
2.1 -3.1
-0.7 4.1
#
3.8 1.5
-1.2 1.1
```

Code:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    contents=[]
    for row in f:
        if not row.startswith("#"):
            line_data=[]
            for x in row.split():
                line_data.append(float(x))
            contents.append(line_data)
print(contents)
```

Result:

```
[[2.1, -3.1], [-0.7, 4.1], [3.8, 1.5], [-1.2, 1.1]]
```

Comment: can it be done without list comprehension? Thanks for the help

Comment: @Proofnothing10x – I assume your comment was intended for my answer, so I put my reply there (so I get notifications).

Comment: @leaf_yakitori – Your code returns only two levels of nested lists, i.e. it ignores the block structure denoted by the `#` signs. According to the question, three levels of nested lists are desired.